# 時系列のフォーマットを変更と描画

Tags: python, pandas

1.時間のフォーマットを変更したいですが、

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'],format='%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分')
```

うまくいかないんです。
正しい書き方は何ですか。

2.散布図の作り方、

```
plt.plot_date(datetime, temp)
```

うまくいかないんです。
正しい書き方は何ですか。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[Pandasの日付データと文字列をそれぞれ変換する方法〜strアクセサとdtアクセサ](https://itstudio.co/2020/09/05/10989/), [【毎日Python】Pythonでデータフレームから散布図を作成する方法｜DataFrame.plot.scatter](https://kino-code.com/python_pandas_scatter/), [Matplotlib - 散布図(Scatter plot)の徹底解説 (単一・複数系列/3D、CSVからの描画と装飾(タイトル、ラベル、目盛線、凡例、マーカーのサイズ／色／種類／透明度))](https://ai-inter1.com/python-scatterplot/)

Comment: 「うまくいかないんです。」とはどういうことでしょうか？（質問1、2とも）エラーが発生した場合にはエラーメッセージを追記ください。画像はエクセルのようですが、pandasでどのように表示されているのかを記入された方が良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` 項目が既に日時データである場合
@kunif 氏がコメントで記しているように `dt` アクセサで変換可能
(ちなみに `pd.to_datetime(STRING, formt='')` は文字列を日時データに変換する方法)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.date_range(start="2023-3-20", periods=40, freq="30min")
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': rng,
    'temp': np.random.randn(40),
})
df['日時'] = df.datetime.dt.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分')   # 日時データを文字列へ変換

print(df.dtypes)
# datetime    datetime64[ns]
# temp               float64
# 日時                object
# dtype: object
```

---

plotの場合, 日時データを扱うなら文字列ではなく `datetime64`が望ましいでしょう
(以下は colabでの表示の場合)

```py
# !pip install japanize-matplotlib
import japanize_matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.loc[len(df)] = [pd.Timestamp('2023-3-21'), 3]
df['日時'] = df.datetime.dt.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.plot_date(df['datetime'], df['temp'], fmt='o', xdate=True)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]